# scan column for a variable and select the row

Tags: excel, vba, select, transpose

i have a big datasheet and i need a code to scan a column( screenshot "selection") for  a x or add a checkbox. If there is a x  the row should be selected and some of the columns should be transposed into a new table.

i have an code to scan the column for x and have the code to transpose the columns i need but i need some help to combine these codes together.

1. scan column(selection) for an x and select the rows
2. transpose some cells(selected colums)  of the selected row into a new table ( i have the code)

```
For Each c In Range("K:K")
 ' If c.Value = "x" Then
  
  ' MsgBox "x found at " & c.Address
  'End If
'Next c
```

```
Sub TransposeColumn2Row()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Myarray() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer
Dim StartCell As Range
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set StartCell = ws1.Range("A1")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws1.Cells(StartCell.Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'copy specific columns into worksheet 2

j = 1
For i = 1 To LastColumn Step 1
    Select Case i
        Case 1, 4, 8, 6, 9, 3, 5 'target columns to copy
            With ws1
                Myarray() = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(LastRow, i)).Value
            End With
            
            With ws2
                .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j, LastRow)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Myarray())
            End With
            j = j + 1
        Case Else
    End Select
Next i
    
Erase Myarray()

End Sub
```

Help me combine these codes
Thx in advance
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-time task, I would use a formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FILTER(A:J, {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0}), K:K="x"))
```

The exact notation depends on local settings (the formula looks different in my case). But this one can be used with `Evaluate` in VBA. Here we mark columns to copy with an array `{1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0}` and then filter the rows with `"x"` in the column K.

As for VBA, this case would be easier to solve with `ListObject` in general case. But we can also `Intersect` columns of interest with marked rows and `.Copy toDestination`:

```
Sub CopyMarked()
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Destination As Worksheet
Dim Data As Range
Dim Criteria As Range
    Set Source = ActiveSheet
    Set Destination = Worksheets.Add(After:=Source)
    Set Data = Source.Range("A:A, C:F, H:I")       ' columns 1,4,8,6,9,3,5
    Set Criteria = Source.Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow
    Intersect(Data, Criteria).Copy 
    Destination.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```